# tic tac toe game in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on a Tic Tac Toe game in Angular and I found this github repo which has this game already built in and it's working fine. After running `npm install` and `npm start` and if I go to this url `localhost:8080` on browser then game will start.

```
https://github.com/siddhartha-gupta/angular2-tic-tac-toe
```

Now I was trying to understand how this game is working and its logic and I got stuck on this line in `server-communicator.service.ts` class:

```
https://github.com/siddhartha-gupta/angular2-tic-tac-toe/blob/master/app/ts/services/server-communicator.service.ts#L20
```

Here is the code:

```
initSocket(callback: Function) {
    // this.socket = io.connect('https://tic-tac-toe-881512.herokuapp.com');
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    this.msgReceiver();
    callback();
}
```

I am not sure what are we running on `localhost port 5000`? I can see we are opening a socket to localhost:5000 but not sure what's the purpose of this? Can anyone explain what are we doing with that `localhost port 5000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without diving too deeply into the details, it looks like this person has a second repository for the server-side component; it runs on port 5000: https://github.com/siddhartha-gupta/nodejs-tic-tac-toe/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Any idea what does that server-side component do? Just checking.

Comment: Looks like it aims to enable multiplayer.